# Problema al guardar la fecha en sql server C# ASP.NET Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

escribo en esta oportunidad porque tengo un problema al guardar la fecha en asp.net core, la base de datos que utilizo es Sql server 2014 y el idioma del servidor es ingles, el problema que presento es que cuando guardo me sale este error:

> String '22-02-2019' was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Y también que edito el mes y me cambie es el día.

Para guardar lo utilizo así:

```
var p = Convert.ToDateTime(periodo);
var fecha = DateTime.ParseExact(p.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"), "dd-MM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

ConversionMoneda conversion = new ConversionMoneda();
conversion.Cmo_periodo = fecha;
conversion.Cmo_factor_de = fromConversion;
conversion.Cmo_created_at = DateTime.Now;
conversion.Cmo_updated_at = DateTime.Now;
context.Add(conversion);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Estoy utilizando entity framework core, en el archivo web.config lo tengo así:

```
<globalization culture="es-ES"  uiCulture="es-ES"  />
```

En mi archivo `JS` utilizo el plugin datepicker:

```
$('.mydatepicker').datepicker({
    format: "dd-MM-yyyy",
    clearBtn: true,
    language: "es",
    autoclose: true,
    keyboardNavigation: false,
    todayHighlight: true
});
```

Pero a la final no me guardar como quiero sino me guarda mes-dia-año tal como lo tiene configurado la fecha y hora en el servidor pero en le formulario seleccionan dia-mes-año, que me recomienda que pueda hacer?

Comment: la propiedad Cmo_periodo de que tipo la defines ? porque no le veo logica a tener una fecha, convertirla a string para depsues aplicar el ParseExact, no tiene ninguna logica esos pasos

Comment: En el modelo la defino como datetime, este es mi modelo: public class ConversionMoneda
    {
        [Key]
        public int ConversionId { get; set; }
        public DateTime Cmo_periodo { get; set; }
        public DateTime Cmo_created_at { get; set; }
        public DateTime Cmo_updated_at { get; set; }
    }

Comment: pero entonces porque no asignas directamente `conversion.Cmo_periodo = p;` si `p` ya es un DateTime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El formato con el cual visualizas en la tabla de la db no tiene ninguna relacion a como visualizas o trabajas esa fecha en la vista.

Si el datepicker usa un formato en concreto solo debes asigurarte que el DateTime lo intepreta correctamente.

Podrias definir la cultura del sitio web mediante configuracion usando

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="es-ES" uiCulture="es-ES" />
</system.web>
```

de esta forma si la UI envia una fecha en formato `dd-MM-yyyy` lo reconocera perfectamente porque la cultura del sitio es la misma, al usar

```
var p = Convert.ToDateTime(periodo);
```

aplicara sin problemas y podras asignar la propiedad

```
conversion.Cmo_periodo = p;
```

Ahora bien al recuperar a fecha y asignarla al `datepicker`quizas debas aplicar formato, para eso se utiliza la libreria [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Lo probe con var p = Convert.ToDateTime(periodo); pero me da error:  String '22-02-2019' was not recognized as a valid DateTime y tmb lo probe con var p = DateTime.ParseExact(periodo, "dd-MM-yyyy",null); y asi no me guarda el mes, a que se puede deber?

Comment: no pongas null en el ultimo parametro, debes definir la cultura `var p = DateTime.ParseExact(periodo, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`, no te guarda el mes? eso no existe, no hay fecha sin mes

Comment: Anexandole el CultureInfo.InvariantCulture si me funciono y ahora si visualiza la fecha bien, tengo una duda que me confundio un poco el estandar ISO-8601, uno lo esta utilizando al definir el formato personalizado dd-MM-yyyy?

Answer (score 0):

Los tipos de dato date/time en SQL Server no tienen un formato guardado. Datetime guarda su valor en 2 valores enteros (uno para fecha y otro para el tiempo). Al momento de leer los datos, le puedes dar el formato que desees.
Te recomiendo que siempre utilices formatos de fecha acordes al estándar ISO-8601. YYYYMMDD o YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss

Comment: Un ejemplo de como aplicarlo? como se podria guardar y mostrar aplicando ISO-8601?

Comment: SSMS lo muestra con un formato default que no se puede cambiar. Cada aplicación puede mostrar el formato que se desee. Se puede usar [CONVERT()](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) para mostrar el formato que se necesite, pero al hacerlo deja de ser un valor de fecha para convertirse en texto.